Assist with data source relationships and transformation within Power BI Desktop
I need help establishing data transformation and relationships within Power BI Desktop among three table queries.  Here are three example sources: Customer, OnlineUser, and OnlineUserFact.
Entity-Relationship rules:

There will always be a Customer record.
OnlineUser will always include customer_id (distinct), but not all Customer records will have a related OnlineUser record (OnlineUser is optional to Customer).
OnlineUserFact will always include onlineuser_id (distinct), but not all OnlineUser records will have a related OnlineUserFact record (OnlineUserFact is optional to OnlineUser).

What I need in the data model:
A single "CustomersMod" table including all Customer columns, onlineuser_id (null-able), and OnlineUserFact (null-able) columns.
Any help will be appreciated!
What I've tried:

Merging query Customer and OnlineUser (left join on customer_id) into CustomersWithOrWithoutUsers, and then merging CustomersWithOrWithoutUsers and OnlineUserFact (left join onlineuser_id) into CustomersMod.
Merging query OnlineUser and OnlineUserFact (left join on onlineuser_id) into UsersWithOrWithoutOnlineUserFact, and then merging Customer and UsersWithOrWithoutOnlineUserFact (left join on customer_id) into CustomersMod.

Each of these attempts end up with null OnlineUserFact column values in the final CustomersMod table.  I'm assuming this has something to do with one-to-one cardinality conflicts.
The SQL solution for the table relationships might be:
SELECT
    c.*,
    ou.id,      -- (null-able)
    oufact.column1, -- (null-able)
    oufact.column2, -- (null-able)
    oufact.column3  -- (null-able)
FROM
    Customer c
    LEFT JOIN OnlineUser ou ON c.customer_id = ou.customer_id
    LEFT JOIN OnlineUserFact oufact ON ou.onlineuser_id = oufact.onlineuser_id

